# Server error 500 (transferring opencart to new server)

Tags: php, server, opencart

I am transferring eCommerce site to new server. Uploaded complete website and created database. Its showing 'server error 500'; kindly help me on this.

Comment: can you show apache error.log?

Comment: Did you update your config.php files?

Comment: I would check the .htaccess file to ensure the settings in it are compatible with your new server. Try loading in the default .htaccess file from OpenCart (extract if from a fresh OpenCart downloaded zip) and see if it fixes the issue. If so, you can now narrow down which setting in the old .htaccess file it causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I might be a bit late, but for anyone else struggling with 500 Server Errors in OpenCart – the first thing to do when debugging these is to **look into your server's error log and find the exact error message**.

If there aren't any, you may need to enable them explicitly by adjusting the **error_reporting**, **display_errors** and **log_errors** settings in your PHP configuration. You can also temporarily change them in your main index.php file directly.

Once you know the exact error message, fixing it is a simple process.

We've covered some of the most common OpenCart error messages causing 500 Server Errors in our blog post: [Server Errors and Blank Pages in OpenCart: Most Common Causes](https://multimerch.com/blog/blank-pages-in-opencart-most-common-causes/).

I'd recommend against trying to fix blank pages and 500 Server Errors without being able to look into the error log. These issues can be caused by pretty much anything starting from your server configuration and restrictions to broken OpenCart code so you really need to know what you're dealing with.

In your particular case, it is most likely caused by your new server configuration or the fact that you haven't adjusted OpenCart config files (**config.php** and **admin/config.php**) after the migration.